# Configuring Apache, Tomcat, & SVN on Snow Leopard Server

Tags: svn, apache, tomcat, osx-snow-leopard

I have a Mac mini with Snow Leopard Server installed on it.  I need to have Tomcat, Apache, and SVN running on this system, with Apache configured to pass JSP through to Tomcat, and SVN accessible through Apache.  I've tried all sorts of things, and googled extensively, but can't find the right combination that works.  I've been able to get svn://myname@localhost to work, but svn://myname@myserver.com won't work.  Nor will Apache pass through to Tomcat if I connect to the server at port 80.  All I get is the text of the JSP file.

I have a router in front of the server, with a fixed IP, and am using port forwarding to connect the outside world to the server.  If I forward port 80 to 8080 internally, then JSP pages load fine.  But passing 80 to 80 returns the above behavior.

Are there any how-to's that address this particular combination?  Is there anyone here who has experience with this?  Any help would be most appreciated.

I'm running OS X 10.6.3 Server.  Tomcat 6.0.26. Apache is what came installed on Snow Leopard Server.  SVN is the latest binary download (don't remember off hand, but it was within the last couple of weeks).  I've enabled the jk_module, dav_svn_module, and authz_svn_module modules in Server Admin.

Please help.  This has had me totally wrapped around the axle for the last week now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this partially resolved, and am not really worrying about the rest 'til later, if I need to at all.

1)  I was directed to [this rather long document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/server/subversionwithxcode3.html), which describes in great detail how to get SVN working under Apache on SL Server.  I'd had many disparate pieces of it done, as spelled out in various articles I found on the web.  But none of them got all of it right, and there were multiple parts that I hadn't done.  Kinda fascinating, really.  That aspect of this configuration works really well, now.

2)  I ended up going back to the original configuration I had for Tomcat:  I forward port 80 from the router to port 8080 on the server.  It works.  It's not doing what I thought could be done, which is have 80 go to 80, and have Apache automatically forward any JSP-specific page requests to Tomcat at 8080.  I've read multiple articles that claim just that.  But nothing I tried worked.

The nearest I got was setting up some ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse commands in the http.conf file to forward JSP to Tomcat.  But what that really does is forward a command like this:

www_dot_myserver_dot_com/jsp/mypage.jsp (friggin' only-one-link-'til-you're-one-of-the-blessed rule) to the target.  Anything with the /jsp/ sub-dir.  I don't want it that way.

Oh, well.  I don't really have any more time to spend on it, so I'll stick with the port forwarding.  As things move forward, I will be moving different pieces to different boxes, so I'll have to mess around with the configurations more anyway.

Just in case anyone is interested....